# syntax error, unexpected '{' php

Tags: php

My php code gives the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 8
```

PHP Code:

```
$data = '<?php
# 1 = ON; 0 = OFF.  
$str = '{                           //line 8
 "name": "10.000000,106.000000",
     "Status": {
     "code": 200,
     "request": "geocode"
 },
  "Apps": [ {
  "App1": 1,
  "App2": 0,    
  "App3": 1,
  "App4": 0,
  "App5": 0,
  "App6": 0
 } ]
 }';
   echo $str;
 ?>';
```

I'm a newbie to php. Can anybody help me finding where I'm wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You have to escape the `'` inside the string: `\'`

Comment: You have `'` inside `'`, which ends the string. Escape it with `\'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the second `'` in here:

```
        +-- open string constant
        V
$data = '<?php
    # 1 = ON; 0 = OFF.  
    $str = '{   
           ^
           +-- close string constant
```

is *terminating* the string constant. You probably want to escape it (and the other one just before the final `echo`) such as:

```
$data = '<?php
    # 1 = ON; 0 = OFF.  
    $str = \'{   
       blah, blah, blah
    }\';
    echo $str;
?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string got terminated by the single quote (apostrophe) right before the `{` character. Escape the `'` character using `\'`.

```
$data = '<?php
# 1 = ON; 0 = OFF.  
$str = \'{                           //line 8
 "name": "10.000000,106.000000",
     "Status": {
     "code": 200,
     "request": "geocode"
 },
  "Apps": [ {
  "App1": 1,
  "App2": 0,    
  "App3": 1,
  "App4": 0,
  "App5": 0,
  "App6": 0
 } ]
 }\';
   echo $str;
 ?>';
```

Comment: You mean :
$data = '<?php
# 1 = ON; 0 = OFF.  
$str = \'{                           //line 8
 "name": "10.000000,106.000000",
     "Status": {
     "code": 200,
     "request": "geocode"
 },
  "Apps": [ {
  "App1": 1,
  "App2": 0,    
  "App3": 1,
  "App4": 0,
  "App5": 0,
  "App6": 0
 } ]
 }\';
   echo $str;
 ?>';
Yes, I did that already but it was still giving me the same error.

Comment: @catherine I've added the corresponding code that should work.

Comment: I don't understand. I updated my php but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: sorry, i was calling the wrong php. Its done. Thanks so my all of you.